# Difference between success and unhighlight in jQuery Validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

What's the difference between `success` and `unhighlight` in the jQuery Validate plugin?

```
element.validate({
   success: function(args){...}
   unhighlight: function(args){...}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`unhighlight`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#unhighlight) is the complementary function to `highlight` and they are used for toggling the class of valid/invalid elements respectively.  If you use `highlight`, then you should also use `unhighlight` to do the opposite.

```
$("#myform").validate({
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    },
    ....
```

[`success`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#success) is used for showing the error message element on a "valid" element.  Normally, when an element is "valid", the error message is simply hidden.  By using `success`, you can show the error message element and force it to display something like `"ok"` upon successful validation.

```
$("#myform").validate({
    success: function(label) {
        label.text("Ok!")
    },
    ....
```